# Android Studio (Kotlin): Error when starting the debugger

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am a novice at Android and Kotlin, and I've started to follow the "fundamentals" codelabs.  I also have an experimental app of my own that I wrote from scratch.  It runs nicely on the emulator and the device, but now I can no longer run it in the debugger (using the "bug" icon).  When I do that, I immediately get this stack trace:

```
access:-1, Linux (libcore.io)
access:131, ForwardingOs (libcore.io)
access:76, BlockGuardOs (libcore.io)
access:131, ForwardingOs (libcore.io)
access:7719, ActivityThread$AndroidOs (android.app)
checkAccess:281, UnixFileSystem (java.io)
exists:813, File (java.io)
updateLoader:75, ResourceOverlays (com.android.tools.deploy.instrument)
addResourceOverlays:37, ResourceOverlays (com.android.tools.deploy.instrument)
addResourceOverlays:110, InstrumentationHooks (com.android.tools.deploy.instrument)
getResources:1312, LoadedApk (android.app)
createSystemContext:2993, ContextImpl (android.app)
getSystemContext:2647, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleBindApplication:6621, ActivityThread (android.app)
access$1500:256, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleMessage:2090, ActivityThread$H (android.app)
dispatchMessage:106, Handler (android.os)
loopOnce:201, Looper (android.os)
loop:288, Looper (android.os)
main:7842, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:548, RuntimeInier (com.android.internal.os)
main:1003, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

In this frame:

```
exists:813, File (java.io)
```

I see:

```
this = {File@19636} "/data/data/com.example.codegame/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/res"
```

Any idea which file this is supposed to be?  There is no `/data/` folder on my machine!

I should add that:

1. Earlier, I was able to start the app in the debugger.  I guess at some point I made some changes that are causing the problem, but I have no idea what!
2. If I just run the app (in the emulator), I can attach the debugger after it started.
3. This doesn't happen with other projects.
4. This error persists when I close and re-open Studio.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: After a day or two this stopped happening.